# Ionic 3 Firebase login stop on error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

Ok so I made a login page and if you enter correct credentials it pushes you to the needed page but if you enter WRONG credentials it still pushes u there and just shows an error which u can just close and reach the after login page, what should I do? here is my login function:

```js
  async login(user: User) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: "Failure to connect/Invalid Credentials",
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    try {
      const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      if (result) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      toast.present();
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    }
  }
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an await call. When using the `async` keyword you need to resolve promises with `await`:

```
const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
```